# Something like expand.grid on a list of lists

Tags: r

I have three text documents stored as a list of lists called "dlist":

```
dlist <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c"), text = list(c("the", "quick", "brown"), c("fox", "jumps", "over", "the"), c("lazy", "dog"))), .Names = c("name", "text"))
```

In my head I find it helpful to picture dlist like this:

```
   name  text
1  a     c("the", "quick", "brown")
2  b     c("fox", "jumps", "over", "the")
3  c     c("lazy", "dog")
```

How can this be manipulated be like below?  The idea is to graph it, so something that can be melted for ggplot2 would be good.

```
  name  text
1    a   the
2    a quick
3    a brown
4    b   fox
5    b jumps
6    b  over
7    b   the
8    c  lazy
9    c   dog
```

That's one row per word, giving both the word and its parent document.

I have tried:

```
> expand.grid(dlist)
  name                  text
1    a     the, quick, brown
2    b     the, quick, brown
3    c     the, quick, brown
4    a fox, jumps, over, the
5    b fox, jumps, over, the
6    c fox, jumps, over, the
7    a             lazy, dog
8    b             lazy, dog
9    c             lazy, dog

> sapply(seq(1,3), function(x) (expand.grid(dlist$name[[x]], dlist$text[[x]])))
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
Var1 factor,3 factor,4 factor,2
Var2 factor,3 factor,4 factor,2

unlist(dlist)
  name1   name2   name3   text1   text2   text3   text4 
    "a"     "b"     "c"   "the" "quick" "brown"   "fox" 
  text5   text6   text7   text8   text9 
"jumps"  "over"   "the"  "lazy"   "dog"

> sapply(seq(1,3), function(x) (cbind(dlist$name[[x]], dlist$text[[x]])))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]   
[1,] "a"  "the"  
[2,] "a"  "quick"
[3,] "a"  "brown"

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]   
[1,] "b"  "fox"  
[2,] "b"  "jumps"
[3,] "b"  "over" 
[4,] "b"  "the"  

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]  
[1,] "c"  "lazy"
[2,] "c"  "dog"
```

It's fair to say I'm befuddled by the various apply and plyr functions and don't really know where to start.  I've never seen a result like in the "sapply" attempt above, and don't understand it.

Comment: You can format it more closely to what you have in your head, like this: `dlist<-list(a=c("the","quick","brown"),...)`. Doing so may also simplify the answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks Frank, and the Josh's setNames function showed me how to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you convert your `dlist` to a named list (a better suited structure in my opinion), you can use `stack()` to get the two column data.frame you want.

(The `rev()` and `setNames()` calls in the second line are just one of many ways to adjust the column ordering and names to match the desired output shown in your question.)

```
x <- setNames(dlist$text, dlist$name)
setNames(rev(stack(x)),  c("name", "text"))
#   name  text
# 1    a   the
# 2    a quick
# 3    a brown
# 4    b   fox
# 5    b jumps
# 6    b  over
# 7    b   the
# 8    c  lazy
# 9    c   dog
```

Comment: +1 I have *no* idea how this works. Now I get to find out and I like that.

Comment: Thanks for three great new functions, especially for setNames which means I can follow Frank's comment after the fact, instead of going right back to the beginning.

Comment: @SimonO101 -- Oh good. I had actually held back on posting this at first, because it packs so many steps in a couple of lines. Based on your and nacnudus' comments, though, I'm glad I did. (FWIW, I'd probably *really* use `with(dlist, setNames(text, name))`, myself.)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, maybe more generalizable:

```
do.call(rbind, do.call(mapply, c(dlist, FUN = data.frame, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))

#     name  text
# a.1    a   the
# a.2    a quick
# a.3    a brown
# b.1    b   fox
# b.2    b jumps
# b.3    b  over
# b.4    b   the
# c.1    c  lazy
# c.2    c   dog
```

Comment: This is better than Simon O'Hanlon's suggestion since it allows for data frames with multiple columns (like "name" in the example) to be expanded into rows based on a list column !!!

Answer (score 1):

Josh's answer is much sweeter but I thought I'd throw my hat in the ring.

```
dlist <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c"), 
    text = list(c("the", "quick", "brown"), 
    c("fox", "jumps", "over", "the"), c("lazy", "dog"))), 
    .Names = c("name", "text"))

lens <- sapply(unlist(dlist[-1], recursive = FALSE), length)

data.frame(name = rep(dlist[[1]], lens), text = unlist(dlist[-1]), row.names = NULL)

##   name  text
## 1    a   the
## 2    a quick
## 3    a brown
## 4    b   fox
## 5    b jumps
## 6    b  over
## 7    b   the
## 8    c  lazy
## 9    c   dog
```

That being said the list of lists is a bit of an awkward storage method.  A list of vectors (particularly named lists of vectors) would be easier to deal with.