# sub-list element combinations within sublists of unequal lengths

Tags: r

How can I incrementaly do expand.grid on the following sublists.

```
list ( list ( c (1,4,6) , c ( 2 , 5 )),list ( c (9,12), c(3,6), c(1,1),c(6,9)),list(c(8,10),c(integer(0)),c(integer(0)),c(integer(0)), c(integer(0)),c(integer(0))))
```

I am aware that I can use the following expression as to do expand grid on a list, [Something like expand.grid on a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326354/something-like-expand-grid-on-a-list-of-lists).

```
do.call ( rbind , do.call ( mapply, list, FUN = data.frame, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))
```

However as my lists do not have equal length this function does not work.

Desired output should be a set of sublists with the combinations of the different sublists. Something like below, please notice that the lists are not all combinations possible but elements are used only once and always incrementaly as per the order of the elements in the sub-segments.

```
1 2 
4 2 
6 2 
1 5  
4 5 
6 5  

9  3 1 6
9  6 1 6
12 3 1 9
12 6 1 9 

8  integer(0) integer(0) integer(0) integer(0) integer(0)
10 integer(0) integer(0) integer(0) integer(0) integer(0)
```

Comment: Isn't that just `lapply(list_of_lists, expand.grid)`? You can filter out the `integer(0)`s if you like (`expand.grid` can't handle them). Also, FYI `mapply( ... , SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` is just `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do.call(expand.grid,...)` here, however, you must apply it to each top-level list component independently, which can be done with `lapply()`. Also, for the third top-level component, you must filter out the empty vectors, otherwise they would render the result of the `expand.grid()` empty.

```
l <- list(list(c(1,4,6),c(2,5)),list(c(9,12),c(3,6),c(1,1),c(6,9)),list(c(8,10),c(integer(0)),c(integer(0)),c(integer(0)),c(integer(0)),c(integer(0))));
lapply(l,function(x) do.call(expand.grid,Filter(function(x) length(x)>0L,x)));
## [[1]]
##   Var1 Var2
## 1    1    2
## 2    4    2
## 3    6    2
## 4    1    5
## 5    4    5
## 6    6    5
##
## [[2]]
##    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
## 1     9    3    1    6
## 2    12    3    1    6
## 3     9    6    1    6
## 4    12    6    1    6
## 5     9    3    1    6
## 6    12    3    1    6
## 7     9    6    1    6
## 8    12    6    1    6
## 9     9    3    1    9
## 10   12    3    1    9
## 11    9    6    1    9
## 12   12    6    1    9
## 13    9    3    1    9
## 14   12    3    1    9
## 15    9    6    1    9
## 16   12    6    1    9
##
## [[3]]
##   Var1
## 1    8
## 2   10
```

---

Whoa, as alistaire pointed out in his comment, `expand.grid()` works on a single argument consisting of a list of vectors, in addition to the more common usage of passing multiple vector arguments to it. It's hard to keep of track of which R functions support this dual interface and which don't. For example, `cumsum()` supports it, but `sum()` does not. Anyway, here's how the solution can be simplified to take advantage of this convenience:

```
lapply(l,function(x) expand.grid(Filter(function(x) length(x)>0L,x)));
```